# Insert Data into MySQL without reloading the page (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

HTML Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>

<form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>

<form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>

<script src='insert.js'></script>
```

`Insert.JS` file code:

```
   $('.myform').submit(function(){
    return false;
});

$('.insert').click(function(){
    $.post(     
        $('#.yform').attr('action'),
        $('.myform :input').serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('.result').html(result);
        }
    );
});
```

**Expected Result:** When user clicks on `Insert` button, the code runs `insert.php` file in the background (No reloading of the page), and display the result inside this `<p id='result'></p>`

**Original Result:** Only the first `insert` button code works. The other `insert` button redirects the user to `insert.php`.

I know, This is probably because of some same `classes`. But I do not know, how to fix it. I would like to make changes only in my Jquery code. I do not want to add different classes for each form.

Comment: You should use `ajax` if you want not to reload your page.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna sir,  I guess, I am already using it. The first `form` works perfectly fine. But not others.

Comment: you have 3 forms and i see `.myform` is the common class. if you submit your form with the class handler e.g `$('.myForm')` then 3 forms submitted. If you want to submit your 2nd form, then you can add an `id` attribute for that form and and submit your form by that id. e.g `$('#your_form_id').serializeArray()`.

Comment: I think $.submit will not cancel the submit event. Try cancelling the onsubmit event of form. <form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' onsubmit="mySubmitFunction()" >. If it is not working cancel the click event of form too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dealing with click events, you could override default forms' submit behavior and use `$(this)` to work only with form being submitted.

```
$(".myform").submit(function(e) {
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  var resultDiv = $(this).find(".result");
  $.post(url, data, function(result) {
    resultDiv.html(result);
  });
  return false;
});
```

1. grab the forms and override their submit function
2. get the data from the form that is being submitted
3. get the url to post to from this very form
4. grab immediate child result (instead of all of them)
5. pass your own success function to do whatever you need, in this case append the result

Modify this code if you want to post data from **all** the forms at once.

Comment: Works fine, but it execute all form's, instead of just one.

Comment: are you sure it submits all of them or is it just appending html 3 times?

Comment: Edited code now grabs only result of submitted form and appends html. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

Sir I think You need to try Just Ajax code like this.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'URL_OF_YOUR_PAGE',
            data:  $('.myform :input').serializeArray(),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (r) {
                //SUCCESS CODE
           }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit of your second form then attached an id to that form, and submit your form data by that id. If your provided code fine then this code should be worked. If your three forms have same class then you can not catch that form uniquely from jquery side only.

```js
$('.myform').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});


$('.insert').click(function(){
    $.post(     
        $('.myform').attr('action'),
        $('#secondForm').serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('.result').html(result);
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='insert.php' method='post' id="firstForm" class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>

<form action='insert.php' method='post' id="secondForm" class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>

<form action='insert.php' method='post' id="thirdForm" class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Redirects the user to insert.php

Comment: You should use `preventDefault()` in order to prevent submitting your form by `e.preventDefault();` see my edits.

Comment: It execute all form at once.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your js code. change like this:

```
$('.insert').click(function(){
    $.post(     
        $('.myform').attr('action'),
        $('.myform :input').serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('.result').html(result);
        }
    );
});
```

jquery selector error

Comment: It execute all forms + redirect user to insert.php

Comment: $('.myform').submit(function(){
    return false;
});                        add these to . it execute all forms because your jquery selector select all elements with class insert.

Comment: Sir, i am not good at Jquery, can you modify your code and give the updated answer Please?

Comment: No your form execute only once. but $('.result').html(result); reflect at three times.because of same class. try browser network tab. there only one request passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQquery AJAX method with multiple options and you need to disable the button after click, this will avoid multiple request to the server.

```
//button click
$(".insert").click(function(e){

        //get the form data and serialize 
        var dataString = $(".myform").serialize();

        //make the AJAX request, dataType is set to json
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SERVER_URL",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",

            //response from the server
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("SUCCESS");
            },

            //No response from the server
            error: function(xhr){
                console.log("ERROR :" + xhr.statusText);
            },

            //capture the request before it was sent to server
            beforeSend: function(){
                // disable the button
                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            },

            //after the response
            complete: function(){
                //enable the button 
                $(this).attr("disabled", false);
            }

        });        
});
```

Comment: Redirects the user to insert.php

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the form in your click handler using `closest`

```
 var theForm = $(this).closest('form');
```

Then you can read that form's action and serialize that forms data:

```
$('.insert').click(function(){
    var theForm = $(this).closest('form');
    $.post(     
        theForm.attr('action'),
        theForm.serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('.result').html(result);
        }
    );
    return false;
});
```

Here's a mock that outputs the forms data into a text box using the same approach:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id0'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>

<form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id1'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>

<form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
    <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id2'/>
    <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
    <p class='result'></p>
</form>

<textarea id='out' style="width:600px;height:250px"></textarea>
<script src='insert.js'></script>

<script>

$('.myform').submit(function(){
    return false;
});

$('.insert').click(function(){
   var theForm = $(this).closest('form');
   var mockData= {};
   mockData["action"] = theForm.attr('action');
   mockData["data"] = theForm.serializeArray();
   $('#out').val(JSON.stringify(mockData));
   /* $.post(     
        theForm.attr('action'),
        theForm.serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('.result').html(result);
        }
        return false;
    );
    */
});
</script>
```

Comment: It execute all forms at once.

Comment: No it doesn't. I have a working demo in which the form data JSON is being added to the text area. If all of your forms are submitting all at once on your actual page then you have a different issue causing it.

Comment: Did you run my snippet? Only the data for the form that the button is in is being saved to the textarea. Same thing should happen with the AJAX post unless you have another issue in your HTML

Comment: But bro, I cannot use different name's like tmdb_id0

Comment: You don't need to. That was only for debugging purposes so you can see that the JSON in the text area is from the correct form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
        <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id' value='2'/>
        <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
        <p class='result'></p>
    </form>

    <form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
        <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id' value='3'/>
        <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
        <p class='result'></p>
    </form>

    <form action='insert.php' method='post' class='myform' >
        <input type='hidden' name='tmdb_id' value='6'/>
        <button class='insert'>Insert</button>
        <p class='result'></p>
    </form>

    <script src='insert.js'></script>
```

insert.js code:

```
$('.myform').submit(function(){
        return false;
});
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("insert");

$('.insert').click(function(){
  for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(elements[i]===this){
      var j=i;
      $.post(
        $(document.getElementsByClassName("myform")[j]).attr('action'),
        $(document.getElementsByClassName("myform")[j]).serializeArray(),
        function(data){
          $(document.getElementsByClassName("result")[j]).html(data);
        }
      );
    }
  }
});
```

insert.php code:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```